# How can I correct this errror with Java FX?

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I am getting below error :

> ERROR: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'*** + and long text errors

**ISSUE1** : When I tried to connect Java FX and MySQL Database, so please help me to solve this problem.

**ISSUE2** :Also were problems in time zone

**THIS IS MY CODE:**

```java
package sample;

import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.DCONST;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DatabaseHandler extends Configs {
    Connection dbConnection;

    public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":"
                + dbPort + "/" + dbname + "? " + "useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);

        return dbConnection;
    }

    public void SignUpUser(User user) {
        String insert = " INSERT INTO " + Const.USER_TABLE + "(" + Const.USER_FIRSTNAME + ","
                + Const.USER_LASTNAME + "," + Const.USER_LOCATION + ","
                + Const.USER_USERNAME + "," + Const.USER_PASSWORD + ","
                + Const.USER_GENDER + ")" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
            prSt.setString(1, user.getFirstname());
            prSt.setString(2, user.getLastname());
            prSt.setString(3, user.getLocation());
            prSt.setString(4, user.getUsername());
            prSt.setString(5, user.getPassword());
            prSt.setString(6, user.getGender());

            prSt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that the database table actually has a column named `password`?

Answer (score 0):

can you give all the stack trace of the error ?But obviously it seems that in your database there is no field with the name password